# How to access sibling controller function in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I have the following controller structure:
[image]

with the following code:

MAIN CONTROLLER:

```
  class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load_defaults();
      }

      public function load_defaults() {

      }

   }
```

CHILD CONTROLLER 1:

```
class Child1 extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->main();
    }

    public function main() {
        echo "function in Child Controller 1";
    }
}
```

CHILD CONTROLLER 2:

```
class Child2 extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->main();
    }

    public function main() {
        echo "function in Child Controller 2";
    }
}
```

My question: How do I call a function located in Child1 controller, from the Child2 controller?

Comment: are you using hmvc ci or simple ci

Comment: I think I am using simple CI. It is in MVC format, It is the only Codeigniter Ive used

Comment: never tryed it but are you getting any error

Comment: No errors. I just dont know how to call a function that is located on the sibling controller class. Is this possible?

Comment: its out of scope in MVC so they have introduced HMVC so you can call different modules !!!

Comment: If you have a general function to be used with many controllers you should make a helper for it so you can auto load the helper and use the function anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to call a controller from another controller, you're doing it wrong. Controllers are there to accept URI requests from the client.

Please try to revisit the problem and see if you can move the common logic to MY_Controller - it will be accessible because all other controllers extending it.

Also a model will be good place to have common functions that will be called from controllers.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is `redirect`. Considering that by CI convention each controller function should be an endpoint for the user, if you want to access a function from another controller then what you are **really** trying to do is redirect them to that controller.

```
function someEndPoint(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('someOtherEndPoint', 'refresh');
}
```